# What is the max speed and duty cycle of an air conditioner's magnetic clutch?

Tags: automotive-engineering, hvac

I am considering using an automobile ac compressor to control the resistance of an exercise machine by engaging and disengaging the magnetic clutch to let it slip.

The max torque should be about 500 Nm.

How long does it take to engage once it is turned on  and what sort of duty cycle can I use to drive it?

Comment: Tip: 'nm' is nanometers. 'Nm' for newton-meters. Capitals matter.

Comment: You need a brake, not a clutch. There are electric metal powder brakes that do what you want. or regular electric over mechanical systems. https://www.warnerelectric.com/products/torque-control-products/electromagnetic-tension/tb-series-basic-tension

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - you may be better off taking the torque from the shaft of a motor/generator (with appropriate reduction via gear or belt)

---

It might be a tricky to get proportional action out of it, if it is designed for on-off operation, as I'm pretty sure would be the case for an A/C compressor.

I would expect the threshold of the current, at which it engages or disengages, to be quite inconsistent, which would limit the quality of closed loop control I could get out of it. I would not expect open loop operation to have good enough reproducibility at all. But load cells are affordable (if necessary, several can be scavenged from a bathroom scale!).

If I wanted a magneto-mechanical actuator with proportional action, the first instinct would be to control of current to the coil, with an anti-hysteresis dither waveform. To control current, you may need to rewire it to remove any contactor switch, if one is built in. The dither waveform is typically superimposed on the control signal to overcome hysteresis. The hysteresis is both magnetic and mechanical.

The dither frequency (100Hz ballpark typical) would in principle be low-pass-filtered out of the output, with a mechanism built into the output for that purpose. But this would present an extra challenge in the case of exercise equipment, since the user would directly feel everything it does with their body, so the filter would have to attenuate much more than is typical for an industrial application, yet be responsive in the single-digit-Hz range at the very least, for a responsive feel. This may be impractical.

In addition, it is possible that dither action could wear out the clutch much faster than without. So again some other solution may be needed. Perhaps sensing and closed loop control of the magnetic field with a cheap flux sensor, as the anti-hysteresis strategy. The control is getting a little more complicated now. (3 cascaded loops: current, flux, force)

It would make for an interesting project, likely not the simplest solution.
You might end up deciding you need  a better actuator, for one thing. Depending on the type of exercise machine, more direct (i.e. geared) action from a motor/generator might be a less challenging way to go, but also not trivial.

Comment: Thanks, Pete! 

As an alternative, I was considering DC injection braking to an AC induction motor.  Could I get your thoughts on that?

Comment: @Steve Dutky -- I think that could be effective. IMO you would still want to sense torque (or force) and control it in a closed-loop. You could put a torque sensor in the motor mount, put a torque sensor that reads out through a differnetial, or perhaps put a load cell in the mounting of a pulley if you are producing force, which might be simplest.

Comment: The electrical aspects of this are a little mode complicated -- the closed loop control has to be careful to also limit speed, and precision motor control is generally a more involved control loop than precision control of an electromagnet. I'd defer to the folks at [electronics.stackexchange.com](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), starting with [previous questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=induction+motor+regeneration+torque) on the topic.

Comment: Thanks again!  Back to ac compressors again, permanently leaving the clutch engaged and using an oil as a working fluid, could I practically use it for hydraulic resistance controlled by a recirc valve?  Would it be able to rotate in both directions?

Comment: @Steve - The idea of using a variable hydraulic resistance is not bad actually. I honestly don't know what it would do if you tried it, but I have to at least guess that it would be misusing the A/C compressor even more... designed for a refrigerant, not oil. Seals might not like it because of different chemistry. Internal forces from sudden start/stop could be higher, because incompressible liquid instead of compressible gas.